# Configure nHibernate for multiple-project solution

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Im doing a project with C# winforms. This project is composed by:

[alt text http://img139.imageshack.us/img139/2540/esquemaw.png](http://img139.imageshack.us/img139/2540/esquemaw.png)

- **Client project:** Windows Forms where user will call the CRUD operations;
- **Server project;**
- **Common Project:** This project will hold the models (in the image only have the model Item);
- **ListSingleton Project:** Remote Object that will do the operations on the models;

Im trying to use a 3 layers style in which the CLIENT and the SERVER will be the **views layer**, the LISTSINGLETON will be the **controller layer** (where all objects are created), and COMMON project is the **models layer**...

I already have all the communication working, but now I need to work on the persistence of the data in a mysql database. I was trying to use nHibernate but I’m having some troubles.

My main problem is how to organize my hibernate configuration.
-   In which project do I keep the mapping? Common project?

- In which project do I keep the hibernate configuration file (App.config)? ListSingleton project?
- In which project do I do this:

  ```
      Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
      cfg.AddXmlFile("Item.hbm.xml");
      ISessionFactory factory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
      ISession session = factory.OpenSession();
      ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction();

      Item newItem = new Item("BLAA");

      // Tell NHibernate that this object should be saved
      session.Save(newItem);

      // commit all of the changes to the DB and close the ISession
      transaction.Commit();
      session.Close();
  ```

In the ListSingleton project? Altho I had reference to the Common Project in the ListSingleton I keep getting error in the addXml line…

---

- And when I have 2 projects one with the models & mappings and another where ill use the hibernate (this project has a reference to the models project), how do i do "cfg.AddXmlFile("User.hbm.xml");" I keep geting "Could not configure datastore from file User.hbm.xml" When i use this 2 project structure.

---

My mapping is correct because I tried with a one-project solution and it worked :X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found out the answers to my questions

> In which project do I keep the
>   mapping? Common project?

As Jamie Ide said, yes it should be in the models layer.

> In which project do I keep the
>   hibernate configuration file
>   (App.config)? ListSingleton project?
>
> In which project do I do this:

This configuration file and all hibernate configuration should be in the controller layer, so its in the ListSingleton project;

> And when I have 2 projects one with
>   the models & mappings and another
>   where ill use the hibernate (this
>   project has a reference to the models
>   project), how do i do
>   "cfg.AddXmlFile("User.hbm.xml");" I
>   keep geting "Could not configure
>   datastore from file User.hbm.xml" When
>   i use this 2 project structure.

You should configure the mapping file as Embedded Resource and Copy if newer at the propierties.

Answer (score 2):

> In which project do I keep the mapping? Common project?

Yes. The mapping files should be in the same project as the models.

> In which project do I keep the hibernate configuration file (App.config)? ListSingleton project?

In the client project. I'm assuming that the client project will pass objects to ListSingleton which will act on them.

> In which project do I do this:

In the client project. I do want to point out that you should only create the ISessionFactory once.

Comment: +1 And I'd like to insist upon the ISessionFactory, this MUST be a singleton throughout your application as it is extremely costly to instantiate.

Comment: Im trying to use a 3 layers style in which the client and the servers will be the **views layer**, the listSingleton will be the **controller layer** (where all objects are created), and common project is the **models layer**... So, with this new information, you think I should keep the configuration file and create the Session @ the Client?  PS: I'm sorry I forgot to add this information to the question...

Comment: I don't know, I've never done anything like that. I would do it in the layer that is responsible for handing out ISessions. ISession is serializable so you could do it in either the client or the controller.